# Explicitly specify default method target in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Is there a best practice in Ruby when it comes to explicitly specifying method targets even when unnecessary?

```
class Foo
    def meth1
        puts "bar"
    end

    def meth2
        # is this better?
        self.meth1

        # or this?
        meth1
    end
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it's just a question of style.

The only thing to keep in mind is that you always have to specify a target for setter methods.

```
foo_count = 4 #creates a local variable named foo_count and sets it to 4
self.foo_count = 4 #sends foo_count=(4) to self
```

The same rule applies if you happen to have a local variable with the same name as a method of your class, though I would say that is a bad practice in itself.

Comment: Thanks for the concise explanation.

Answer (score 1):

As Chuck said earlier, it is mostly a matter of style with the exception he pointed out, and when using private methods.  Any time you use a private method from within an object, you must leave off the `self.` business.

Eg:

```
class Tze
  def meth2
    meth1
  end

  def meth3
    self.meth1
  end

  private
  def meth1
    puts "method 1 invoked"
  end
end
```

Calling `Tze.new.meth2` produces the expected output; however, calling `Tze.new.meth3` raises an error because of `meth1` is being invoked as `self.meth1`.

Comment: Setters are excepted from this rule though. `self.x = 5` is valid notwithstanding that `x=` is a private method